# Spring + hibernate - use Oracle UCP connection pool

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, ucp

I have a basic spring boot application and I have successfully connected to an Oracle DB. However I'd like to use the Oracle's UCP connection pool instead of the default. I have the following `application.properties` config:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.type=oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

However, when querying the db I get:

```
oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Error during pool creation in Universal Connection Pool Manager MBean: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Error during pool creation in Universal Connection Pool Manager: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Universal Connection Pool configuration: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to create factory class instance with provided factory class name: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:368) ~[ucp.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:49) ~[ucp.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:80) ~[ucp.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.ucp.admin.UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.createConnectionPool(UniversalConnectionPoolManagerMBeanImpl.java:316) ~[ucp.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.startPool(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:623) ~[ucp.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:907) ~[ucp.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:863) ~[ucp.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:855) ~[ucp.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:201) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:395) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:158) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at **** ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

I have the ucp.jar (as downloaded from Oracle's site) in my classpath.

Comment: Apparently some classes cannot be found. Add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet

Comment: Fixed, thank you very much.

Comment: What was the fix ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that I included the whole stacktrace.

Comment: And oracle decided for some reason to not include the missing class name :(. However it looks like you are missing part of the jar (or maybe you need both ucp and odbcp I'm not sure). Without seeing which class is actually missing it is more of a trial and error fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day I gave up on using strictly configuration properties and followed the steps listed here: http://ebcidicrants.blogspot.bg/2015/07/using-oracle-ucp-as-default-datasource.html. These did the trick with a minor change regarding the reading of the configuration

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.ucp")  
@Component 
public class UCPDataSourceProperties {  ... }
```

And

```
@Bean  
@Primary  
@Autowired
public DataSource ucpDataSource(UCPDataSourceProperties properties) throws SQLException {  ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example (without the need for ConfigurationProperties)...

Below is an example snippet of configuration properties in application.properties file:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@someServiceName_tp?TNS_ADMIN=/someLocation/Wallet_someWallet
    spring.datasource.username=someUser
    spring.datasource.password=somePassword
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    spring.datasource.type=oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource
    spring.datasource.oracleucp.connection-factory-class-name=oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl
    spring.datasource.oracleucp.database-name=oracleADBForGraphQL
    spring.datasource.oracleucp.data-source-name=oracleADBForGraphQLDataSource
    spring.datasource.oracleucp.description="Oracle ADB Used For GraphQL"
```

and here are the Oracle dependencies...

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
   <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
   <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.ha</groupId>
   <artifactId>ons</artifactId>
   <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
   <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>osdt_core</artifactId>
   <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>osdt_cert</artifactId>
   <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or shorten production pom form...

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc11-production</artifactId>
   <version>21.1.0.0</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Along with usual JPA dependency of course...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Longer explanation and source can be found here:
https://dzone.com/articles/develop-react-graphql-spring-data-jpa-ucp-oracle
https://github.com/paulparkinson/react-graphql-springboot-jpa-oracle-ucp-example

Answer (score 0):

I find solution form this link: https://gist.github.com/neilcarlocatalan/0e72c8b2bfe6ac54412d2cde533526a1#file-spring-context-xml

here is my dataSource programming implement

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public synchronized DataSource getDataSource() {
    try {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            dataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
            dataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
            dataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:/@DB");
            dataSource.setUser("user");
            dataSource.setPassword("pw");
            dataSource.setConnectionPoolName(CONNECTION_POOL_NAME);
            dataSource.setMinPoolSize(1);
            dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(2);
            dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(1);
            dataSource.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(120);
            dataSource.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(true);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```